# Calculating positions of Moon's ascending and descending nodes

Tags: moon

I am trying to find the position of planets and moon at any specific date which I was able to find using the JPL ephimeris ASCII files.

I am however stuck now at finding the positions of the moon's ascending nodes and descending nodes (Intersection points of moon's orbit and the ecliptic) from that data. I am a newbie and not even sure if that is possible from that data.

Can anyone help me with how I can perform the calculations to get those positions at any given point in time?

Thanks.